# Virtual image of a virtual object

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

During early classes we are taught that real image of a real object is inverted with respect to the object. Similarly virtual image of a real object is erect with respect to object.
My doubt is that can we make a similar analogy for a virtual image of a virtual object and what would it be?

PS: please do not quote the example of two plane mirrors with an object in between them for this. Here I am oriented towards lens and curved mirrors.

Comment: What is an example of a virtual object?

Comment: Can you describe, what kind of mirrors you have, where are mirrrosrs/lense, and where are you

Answer (score -3):

So you want to see  for example the virtual image  from a curved mirror with a  lens? Why not just sketch a few beams of light and see yourself, that the second virtual picture is also erect.

Comment: You could have said this in comment section this is not the answer

Comment: the answer that the second virtual image is also erect was included. Why should an answer not suggest how you can find it yourself?